# isabelle termination with distance of real numbers

Tags: isabelle, termination

maybe someone can help me with a termination proof in Isabelle. I am trying to construct from the list A a new sub-list B. For constructing B, I read again and again of the whole A. Take out elements and use the result for the search for the next element. I designed a simple example to illustrate that:

given is a list of random real numbers. And we say that a number P is on the list, if an item from the list is greater than P.

```
definition pointOnList :: "real list ⇒ real ⇒ bool" where
  "pointOnList L P ≡ ∃ i. i < length L ∧ P < L!i"
```

I create a function that always take the next larger element.

```
fun nextPoint :: "real list ⇒ real ⇒ real" where
  "nextPoint (X#Ls) P = (if (X > P)
    then (X)
    else (nextPoint Ls P))"
```

And now I'm trying to create a new sorted part-list by take out the next larger element than P but less than Q with `nextPoint` and continuing with this.

```
function listBetween :: "real list ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real list" where
  "pointOnList L P ⟹ pointOnList L Q ⟹ listBetween L P Q = (if(P ≤ Q)
  then(P # (listBetween L (nextPoint L P) Q))
  else([]))"
```

I have already demonstrated `nextPoint` always returns a growing number:

```
lemma foo: "pointOnList P A ⟹ A < (nextPoint P A)"
```

the termination proof with `relation "measure (size o fst o snd)“` not working for real numbers…and now I don’t know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show termination in Isabelle, you have to show that the recursive calls follow a wellfounded relation. The easiest way to do that is to give a termination measure returning natural number that becomes smaller with every call. That does not work with real numbers because they are not wellfounded – you could have something like 1 → 1/2 → 1/4 → 1/8 → …

The termination measure to use in your case would be the number of list elements that fulfil the condition, i.e. `length (filter (λx. P ≤ x ∧ x ≤ Q)) l`. However, note that your definition fails to work if Q is larger than all numbers in the list.

Your definition is somewhat laborious and complicated. I recommend the following definition:

```
listBetween L P Q = sort (filter (λx. P ≤ x ∧ x ≤ Q) L)
```

or, equivalently,

```
listBetween L P Q = sort [x ← L. x ∈ {P..Q}]
```

Note, however, that this definition does not throw away multiple occurrences of the same number, i.e. `listBetween L 0 10 [2,1,2] = [1,2,2]`. If you want to throw them away, you can use `remdups`.

Also note that something like `pointOnList L P ≡ ∃ i. i < length L ∧ P < L!i` is pretty much never what you want – there is no need to work with explicit list indices here. Just do `∃x∈set L. P < x`.

Answer (score 1):

The termination argument `relation "measure (size o fst o snd)"` does not work for several reasons:

- With your lemma `foo` you have just proven that the value increases. But for termination you need a decreasing measure. So you might want to use the difference

  ```
  relation "measure (λ (L,P,Q). Q - P)"
  ```
- Even then there is the problem that `measure` expects a mapping into the natural 
  numbers and `Q - P` is a real number, so this does not work. You used `size` before, but your lemma `foo` states nothing about the connection between `size` and `<`. Moreover, `<` is not a well-founded order over the real numbers.
- Eventually, I would try to avoid the reasoning on reals in this simple example at all and take as measure something like

  ```
  measure (λ (L,P,Q). length [ A . A <- L, P < A])"
  ```

  and adapt the statement of `foo` accordingly.

Comment: This is a notation for list comprehension. So it means the list composed of the elements of L, in the same order, that are greater than P.

Comment: do not be surprised, I asked what is the meaning of `[A ← L. P <A]` and deleted it shortly thereafter. Thanks for your quick response.